# Select HTML Tag Is Not Working with VueJs3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select, vuejs3, html-select

I am using VueJs3 in my POS Web Application, I am Fetching Product Categories and want to loop these categories in Select Tag where the user can select a category and then relevant to that category products will appear but I am stuck at that point where I am getting product categories in JSON format by calling API call using Axios and stored in the categories data property

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: "ProductComponent",
    data() {
        return {
            items: 18,
            category: null,
            categories: [],
            brands: [],
            products: [],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.GetAllCategories();
        this.GetAllProducts();
    },
    methods: {
        ChangeCategory() {
            alert('Category Changed');
        },
        // Stored To Cart
        addToCart(id) {
            alert(id);
        },

        // Get All Categoris
        async GetAllCategories() {
            // alert("I am Called");
            await axios.get('api/categories')
                .then(res => {
                    this.categories = res.data;
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error(err);
                });
        },
        // Get All Products
        async GetAllProducts() {
            await axios.get('api/products')
                .then(res => {
                    this.products = res.data;
                    console.log(res.data);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error(err);
                });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

When I loop these categories with Select then these categories are not looping with select options here is my html code

```
            <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                <select style="background: #F9F9F9" class="browser-default">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>All Categories</option>
                    <option v-for="cat in categories" :key="cat.id" value="{{ cat.id }}"> {{ cat.id }} Select</option>
                    <label for="category" class="">Product Category</label>
                </select>
            </div>
```

and amazing thing is that when I tested with this below code

```
<p v-for="cat in categories" :key="cat.id">{{ cat.category_name }}</p>
```

then all product categories show as they should be shown in the select's options and moreover when I apply ***browser-default*** class to select then started looping but the UI Not good and the CSS code of browser-default is below

```
select.browser-default {
    display: block;
}
```

I could not figure out where I am wrong and how can I solve this issue, please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: have you tried adding a semicolon before the 'value="{{ cat.id }}"'? like :value=...?

Comment: Yeah I have changed value="{{cat.id}}" to :value="cat.id" but did not working as expected.

Comment: @AdnanAli Your code looks correct and it should work. Looks like categories does not have data or there is any typo in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML should look like this:

```
    <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
      <label for="category" class="">Product Category</label>
      <select id="category" style="background: #f9f9f9" class="browser-default">
        <option value="" selected disabled>All Categories</option>
        <option v-for="cat in categories" :key="cat.id" :value="cat.id">{{ cat.id }} Select</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Mainly - `value="{{ cat.id }}"` should be changed to `:value="cat.id"`.

Comment: Yeah I have changed value="{{cat.id}}" to :value="cat.id" but did not working as expected.

Comment: Just getting first option ***All Categories*** and other categories are not looping

Comment: Can you confirm `categories` is not empty? i.e. it's being loaded & set properly?

Comment: yeah I have already written code where I loop categories in paragraph in my question there I am getting all categories in <p> tag but just not working with <select> tag

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at following snippet, if your data is there maybe the problem is `input-field` class:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      categories: [{id: 1, category_name : 'aaa'}, {id: 2, category_name : 'bbb'}, {id: 3, category_name : 'ccc'}],
      category: null
    };
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
select.browser-default {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css" integrity="sha512-17AHGe9uFHHt+QaRYieK7bTdMMHBMi8PeWG99Mf/xEcfBLDCn0Gze8Xcx1KoSZxDnv+KnCC+os/vuQ7jrF/nkw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div id="demo">
  <div class=" col s12 m6">
    <label for="category" class="">Product Category</label>
    <select v-model="category" id="category" style="background: #f9f9f9" class="browser-default">
      <option :value="null" selected disabled>All Categories</option>
      <option v-for="cat in categories" :key="cat.id" :value="cat.id">{{ cat.id }} {{ cat.category_name }} - Select</option>
    </select>
    <p>{{ category }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but when I use ***browser-default*** then it works fine but when I removed this class it does not work

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the select tag display try display **flex** or **inline-block** if you don't want to change UI (default select display is inline)

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      categories: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
      this.GetAllCategories();
  },
  methods: {
      async GetAllCategories() { 
          //Simulate axios 
          setTimeout(() => {
              this.categories = [{ id: "first optoion" }, { id: "second option" }];
          }, 2000);
      },
 }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css" integrity="sha512-17AHGe9uFHHt+QaRYieK7bTdMMHBMi8PeWG99Mf/xEcfBLDCn0Gze8Xcx1KoSZxDnv+KnCC+os/vuQ7jrF/nkw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div id="demo">       
    <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
        <select style="display:inline-block">
            <option value="" selected disabled>All Categories</option>
            <option v-for="cat in categories" :key="cat.id" :value="cat.id"> {{ cat.id }} Select</option>
            <label for="category" class="">Product Category</label>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```